# New washing machine using the same valve as the sink, water smells and tastes like plastic

Tags: plumbing, water, washing-machine, smell, hose

So I have been using the same valve for actually two washing machines and a sink, and when I got the new washing machine the problem started appearing. I am guessing this is because of the new washer hose, it is an LG front load washing machine with its original new hose, yet it makes the whole water coming out taste bad and smelly, even if I run it for over a minute - the taste gets minimal after a while though.

So obviously my best bet is to change the hose, but I wanna know if I wait out if this can be hazardous at all, is this a normal thing to happen? I had a few washes but not many, I am guessing it is supposed to be gone at some point of time, but I am not sure if its dangerous in the meanwhile had two other hoses changed in the past and they did not cause this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if washing machine hoses are rated for potable water, with that said I used to drink from a hose all the time and still do. If the water smells bad let it run it may be like many appliances that have to offgas a little and the smell/ taste will go away after a while. I would think that the hoses should be rated for use with potable water since they are connecting to the home water supply. If you are concerned contact the MFG they will have the info on the materials used in the hoses and will probably give the same advice that it will go away after a while.

Comment: Isn't it odd that water essentially passing by the end of a hose takes on a significant taste and odor from it? Really no water that reaches the sink should have contacted that hose, which is presumably downstream of an intermediate valve.

Comment: It is really weird but I have measured contaminants moving up stream in wafer manufacturing, we could not believe it at first, I think the engineer said it was due in part to bernuli? Affect pulling the chemical out of the down stream T but how the ions traveled up stream I never understood we just isolated the plumbing with double valves and a di water flush to prevent the contamination, it really makes sense with static or no flow water.

Comment: Around a 2 months update, the LG still leaves the smell/taste, but much less noticable...